# X-CSRF-TOKEN is not generated by Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, csrf

I followed the guide here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ to build my rest service example and now I am trying to enable the CSRF protection. I read that it should be enabled by default, so if I DON'T include:

> http.csrf().disable()

in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration, the CSRF protectection should be enabled by default, but it does not seem to to be the case. The problem is that the X-CSRF-TOKEN is not generated and not included in my HTTP response in any way.
What am I expected to do, to have the x-csrf-token generated and included in the response and, of course, the csrf protection fully working?

I noticed that, with a similar spring mvc configuration, I get the x-csrf-token generated simply including:

> < security:csrf disabled="false"/>

in my security configuration file. But, with spring boot maybe I am getting something wrong and there is no way to have the csrf token generated. Can anybody help me, perhaps pointing me to a working example? My security configuration is:

```
     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
     {
        http
      // .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
      .and()
      .httpBasic()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .successHandler(new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
      .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
      .and()
      .logout()
      .logoutSuccessHandler(new RestLogoutSuccessHandler());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{
    auth.userDetailsService(restUserDetailService);
}
```

Comment: provide spring security configuration java code in question

Comment: Thanks Kunal, have added my configure() method above.

Comment: How you are calling your rest service ?

Comment: If you are only creating a service that is used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection. check [when to use csrf](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#when-to-use-csrf-protection)

Comment: I know, but my rest service must be called from a web page - a single page application invoking my rest api through javascript (angular js).

Comment: include csrf token in request through java script. check [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax)

Comment: are you making ajax request through javascript?

Comment: Yes, I am making requests through javascript. I expected that spring includes the csrf token in the response headers, so I can use it in the subsequent request, but it does not seem to happen. On the contrary, in spring mvc it works perfectly.

Comment: At the end I sorted out my problem with this article [spring security csrf-protection for rest services](http://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/), hope it could be useful to other people fighting with `spring` as me!

Comment: Thanks for the post. I had the same issue with Spring boot 2.3.2-RELEASE and the above link and @Melvin Sy answer helped me. Only after adding 

.csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())) 

config in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configure method gives back the CSRF token in response cookie.

Answer (score 7):

To include the CSRF Token in your csrf protection, you can include CSRFTokenRepository to generate tokens. To illustrate in your case adding a simple line is enough:

> ```
>  @Override
>  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
>  {
>   http.
>   .csrf()
>   .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()) //HERE !  Defaults XSRF-TOKEN as cookie name and X-XSRF-TOKEN as header name  
>   .authorizeRequests()
>   .anyRequest()
>   .authenticated()
>   .and()
>   .httpBasic()
>   .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
>   .and()
>   .formLogin()
>   .successHandler(new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
>   .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
>   .and()
>   .logout()
>   .logoutSuccessHandler(new RestLogoutSuccessHandler());}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Using Spring security 5.3.0.Final, one of the ways you can generate the **CSRF** token is by setting it in the cookie using the following code below.

```java
 http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
```

You also need to include the generated CSRF token in your request for the server to authorize.

```java
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${cookie['XSRF-TOKEN'].getValue()}" />
    //Code goes here
</form>
```

In the event you're using a JS framework, you need to include the token by setting it in the request header.

Here is an example for a JQuery ajax call.

```js
// Get the CSRF token from the cookie
const csrfCookie= document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)XSRF-TOKEN\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, '$1');
// Add the CSRF token to each ajax request header
settings.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', springCsrfCookie);
};
$.ajax(settings);
```

There are other implementations that will suit your needs documented in the following link by Spring | https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#servlet-csrf

Answer (score 0):

We had pretty similar issue during our security tests where we suspected that we accidentally disable csfr in configure method of websecurityconfig class,by default it is enabled. by changing the congfigure method as shown below , we had spring automatically generate csfr tokens.

websecurityconfig class configure method==>

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {              

     http
     .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/", "/login","/loginError","/home","/interruption").permitAll()                                                          
         .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority(Roles.ROLE_PREFIX.role()+Roles.HALLEYYNT01.role())  
         .antMatchers("/requests").hasAuthority(Roles.ROLE_PREFIX.role()+Roles.CCHALLEYLOGIN.role())
         .antMatchers("/solrequests").hasAuthority(Roles.ROLE_PREFIX.role()+Roles.SOLHALLEYLOGIN.role())
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
     .formLogin()             
         .loginPage("/login")  
         //.failureUrl("/loginError")
         .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
         .defaultSuccessUrl("/")            
         .and()
     .logout().clearAuthentication(true).invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")         
         .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
         //.and() 
     //.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);    
}
```